# How to stop the effect of an event when another effect of the same event occur?

Tags: jquery

consider this is html code:

```
        <table>         
        <tr>
            <td><img id="a11" src="photos/empty.png" /></td>
            <td><img id="a12" src="photos/empty.png" /></td>
            <td><img id="a13" src="photos/empty.png" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><img class="move" id="a21" src="photos/Pawn.png" /></td>
            <td><img class="move" id="a22" src="photos/Pawn.png" /></td>
            <td><img class="move" id="a23" src="photos/Pawn.png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

consider "empty.png" just an empty image

and this is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".move").click(function (){

    //reset the background color of the first row
    $("#a11, #a12, #a13" ).css("background-color" , "");

    //fetch the src attribute of the clicked element
    var src = $(this).attr("src");

    //fitch the id attribute of the clicked element
    var Id  = $(this).attr("id");
    var Id  = "#"+Id;
    var x = Id[2];
    var y = Id[3];

    ////////////////////////

    newx = x - 1;
    newsy = y;

    //form the new id of the above cell
    newId = "#a" + newx + newsy;

    //make the background of this cell 'red'
    $(newId).css("background-color","red");

    //fire event that when click on this cell move the image to it and remove the image from original cell
    $(newId).click(function(){

        $(Id).attr("src","photos/empty.png");
        $(this).attr("src",src);
        $("#a11, #a12, #a13" ).css("background-color" , "");


    });

});

});
```

**the Required:**
when click on any of the cells in the second row, the background of the corresponding above cell change to red

and then when click on it the image move to it.

**The Problem**

the problem occurs when click on the first cell (first pawn #a21)

then click one the second cell (second pawn #a22)

then click one the third cell (third pawn #a23)

then click on the #a13 or #a12 cells ... the corresponding below image will move to it

and I don't want it

I want to remove the effect of the previous event but only the effect of the last event will be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing the current id in click event do the trick.

```
$(newId).click(function(){
    var currentid = "#"+this.id;
    if(newId == currentid){
        $(Id).attr("src","photos/empty.png");
        $(this).attr("src",src);
        $("#a11, #a12, #a13" ).css("background-color" , "");
    }
});
```

hope it helps.